# Amplifying 0.333 Vac signal to 0..3.3 VDC signal: component selection

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, resistors, converter

I am trying to convert a current transformer (60 Hz) signal with an output of 0.333 Vac to a 0..3.3 VDC input signal. I haven't worked on circuits like this in over 10 years so I come seeking wisdom.

1. Can someone help recommend an op-amp to use for this application. I have a 5 VDC supply voltage
2. Do these resistor and capacity values make sense or should these be adjusted?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What DC supply voltages do you have? 3.3VDC only?

Comment: I was just about to update my post when you beat me to it. I have 5VDC

Comment: Probably don't use a polarized capacitor for C1 at least?

Comment: @Spy - Hi, I have rolled-back (i.e. reversed) your edits, as they invalidate existing answers, meaning they then appear wrong or incomplete etc. || On Stack Exchange, once answers have been received, then *generally* the question should not be changed. Clarified (if needed)? Yes. Changed? No (generally). || If you want to ask someone about a schematic in comments, you can use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. Don't try to iterate a question here.

Comment: Also, say I go with two opamps, do them both on one chip. Would it cause any issues if I were to connect the input + to both opamps from the same R4 & R5 voltage divider?

Answer (score 3):

If your microcontroller's ADC accepts 0V-3V3 and you use an opamp powered from 5V, then you need to protect the ADC input incase the opamp outputs more than 3V3. If you use an opamp powered from 3V3, then you don't need to, because it'll never output more than 3V3.

So you need an opamp with the following:

- Works on 3V3 supply
- Rail to rail output, so it has no trouble with the output voltage range
- Not necessarily rail to rail input, but... When the input is not rail to rail it's usually restricted to something like 1.5V away from at least one supply, and your input common mode will be 1.65V so the margin would be thin.
- Gain bandwidth product: not critical since you want a gain of 4.5 at 60 Hz
- Offset: not relevant, since it's AC coupled
- Noise: not relevant, since gain is small and input signal is quite high already
- Other specs like cost, easy to solder, availability: your choice

So: https://www.digikey.fr/en/products/filter/linear/amplifiers/instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687

Select max supply voltage range <= 3V2, in stock, output type:all choices with "rail to rail", [click](https://www.digikey.fr/en/products/filter/linear/amplifiers/instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687?s=N4IgjCBcoCwdIDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRAGYBOABkoA4A2EAgdgFZLLyICqAmGG2ogAugQAOAFyggAypIBOASwB2AcxABfAnwa0ooZJHTZ8RUhQB0fAAQA1ZiGqWGbe4%2Bd13BZ5W-h-MEswQOtQmFC3BwIghlCWeJDo8EsvZKC-dMtKKMdbZL5g-0L8vOtcnUtyYqr2GoiCyxhqxoqQQrjG1xqExrSyujbCzLKcmspexxapouTyYNyxECkZAFUVJUkAeRQAWRw0LABXBRwtAgBaSgMkKEUjs2JIMggRbRALvhuje8eLNkc1zemk0QA)

Unfortunately there's no search on "rail to rail input" so you have to check the datasheets. For example the first one to come up is LMV358 which would be okay since the input common mode limit is 1V away from the positive supply.

You could go to the manufacturers' website (TI, AD, etc) which do have a "rail to rail input" search... or just sort by price, and notice all the cheap opamps by microchip which have rail to rail input and output and will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

If your 333mVAC is RMS you'll want to increase R5 to maybe 3kΩ to keep the op-amp from saturating with a 3.3V supply.

*That's because 0.333VAC RMS is \$\sqrt 2 \cdot 0.333 = 0.471V\$ peak and the output has to be less than 3.3V/2 = 1.65V so the gain has to be less than 3.5. If your feedback resistor R2 is 10kΩ then R1 should be more than 2.85kΩ. Everything like R4/R5, your power supply, etc. has a tolerance so a bit more than that is good.*

You can use any rail-to-rail input/output (RRIO) op-amp that will operate from 3.3V or less. There are many options and picking an optimal one will depend on various other requirements such as cost, availability, package, power draw etc. Perhaps a micropower CMOS one will be okay speed wise for a 60Hz signal if you're not expecting high frequency harmonics. Overkill, but you could also use something like an 80MHz [AD8031](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8031_8032.pdf). Higher frequency op-amps are generally better but you may need to pay more attention to bypassing and perhaps put a whiff of capacitance across R2.

The capacitor values are more-or-less okay, but I think I would like to see a 10uF ceramic cap for C1 and higher values for R1/R2 (maybe by 10:1 and add a few tens of pF across R2). And a ceramic capacitor directly across the op-amp supply pins, of course.

*To determine the gain, the ratio R2/R1 is what matters. So you can get similar results with R2 = 100kΩ and R1 = 30kΩ as with 10kΩ/3kΩ. The advantage of going higher is that C1 can be smaller for the same error (the impedance of C1 adds in quadrature to R1 to cause the gain to be lower at low frequency). Ceramic capacitors have some advantages over electrolytic (which you show for C1), in particular leakage is much less, which will mean the output voltage with 0V input is not higher than expected, cutting into the margin. The error is leakage current * R2. A ceramic capacitor will have leakage so low it is hard to measure. An electrolytic cap might have a uA or two. So if R2 is 100kΩ the error could be 100-200mV. Using higher resistance also allows the op-amp to get closer to the supply rails and saves power.
Ceramic capacitors are also better for bypass applications because they have lower internal resistance than other types (ESR). They have some disadvantages (not easily available/cheap in huge capacitances, and nonlinear votlage/capacitance and temperature/aging drift) but they are not very important in any of the locations here.
Adding a small capacitor across R2 helps stabilize the op-amp, especially if R2 is high value. Stray capacitance, op-amp input capacitance and layout can result in the feedback through R2 having a bit of lag. If the op-amp is fast enough that can result in overshoot/undershoot or even oscillation. A small capacitor such as 10pF or 100pF across R2 = 100kΩ will roughly limit the frequency of the amplifier to about 600kHz/60kHz respectively and will make it more stable. If R2 = 10kΩ you'd use 10x the capacitance for a similar result.*

*To bypass the supply, a ceramic capacitor (low ESR is important here) near the op-amp supply pins is what we want. 1uF or 10uF is adequate here.
You might ask why don't we increase R1/R2 by 100:1 to 1MΩ/300kΩ and then the capacitors can be even smaller, similarly we could increase R4/R5 to 1MΩ each and the bypass capacitor could then be a tiny 100nF. You could do that, however you start to get significant errors from leakages, bias current and that sort of thing. It might be a good choice for a battery powered circuit with a CMOS micropower op-amp, in which case you might reduce the gain a bit more to account for the error in the DC level.*

Comment: I'm not sure on the 0.333V CT output if it is RMS or Vpp.. every datasheet I pull up just says "Output 0.333VAC). 

Can you explain the "high values for R1/R2... by maybe 10:1" a bit more, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Also, can you quickly explain the math behind the 3kohm to keep from saturating? Thank you

One more question, why specifically ceramic caps? Are the better for this application?

Comment: See the italic sections above for explanation vs. recommendation (no italics).

Comment: thank you, very helpful! I understand much better. [I updated the original post schematic per yours and other comments] I also simulated it via an online tool and seems to work well.

The CT output is 333mVac RMS. Would you say this looks good. Any other comments/suggestions? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It would be better to reverse your edit to leave the original, and add the modified schematic to the original. Otherwise answers and comments make little sense.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Thanks, as you commented, the original schematic in the question shouldn't be changed, so I have rolled-back the OP's latest edits.

Comment: thanks, yes I agree as well. Updated with the new one just below. Spehro, does the new schematic make sense?

Comment: Which one of these would be best? I think the first one, it has the smallest input voltage offset and input current bias. https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/compare?s=N4IgzCBcDaICwAYwHZkEYCcIA09kCYBWDANnxzyNIgF1c4oQB6AUwDsmAHAJwHsATAK4BjAC4BnJgDMAlgBtRLbkxltxo7oIC27UQENRM3mwC0vTib1bO4kwCNBUqUsvXJJABzIA-OIC8AHJwAJIA5gBWAMIAQsK8kQDu-MEAIgDiAKrRWtEpAIIBoQBaCQDSAJrRvACK0cileXYASnlplQDyeQBSABahAGLlrQCieQAa1cF5wuOlo0XVcJEzcqEp4nmEMnmRAKT40dF6a%2BVpcqWlaQDKTQj4UsMAasEZefzt1XmjAU124oIAa1G-UefXCoQAEgDXgB1JoAD14G0eYDghC60TyABkACqPfpXBrtfhocoA0IAT3aPXKXVKLQepWC%2BACeWidgCbEioTyIAAvkA

Comment: Or possibly this one as it's a through hole, easier for me solder. https://www.digikey.fr/en/products/detail/rochester-electronics-llc/TLV2784IN/12125210

Comment: I would keep the bypass on R4. You can always leave it out later if you like.  I wouldn't worry too much about offset voltage- R4/R5 have a tolerance that will swamp any offset. Those op-amps should all work. Even a (non-RR input, RR-output) MCP601 should work similarly well (my go-to low cost CMOS op-amp).

Comment: ok great, thank you. I'll try that one out to start with. For the supply by-pass cap, any recommendations, would this one be ok? https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/vishay-beyschlag-draloric-bc-components/VY2101K29Y5SS6UV7/2824534

Comment: Are the resistor values correct as shown in the second circuit? I simulated it using an online tool and one tool give me an output range from 1.65V to 3.22V (0 to 0.333Vrms input) and another gave me number in the 5-7V output range which doesn't make sense?

Comment: See [this](https://i.imgur.com/xAqKc9e.png)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, that what I get with my sim tool as well. However, when I tried to calculate using math, my numbers don't make sense. Following similar steps to example 2, (https://wiraelectrical.com/inverting-op-amp-equation/) I get Vo=13/3Va-10/3Vi which at Vi=0.471V input and Va=1.65V, works out to 5.58V? I must be calculating it incorrectly?

Comment: The C1 capacitive coupling means that the output at the average input voltage of 0V will be 1.65V. So Vo = 1.65V - (10/3)Vi. Gain from the non-inverting input is 1 (think of the capacitor C1 as an open circuit for the purpose of calculating that gain). If it has leakage (imagine a resistor in parallel with C1) it will affect the output voltage, which is why you want a low-leakage cap such as ceramic. If the voltage at the non-inverting input was changing wrt time then things would be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 2):

1. For selecting your OPAMP, it should be rather easy:

- your application is very slow, so no need to take a fast OP-AMP
- take an OPAMP that is designed for single supply at 5V (or 3.3V, whatever you decide to use)
- if you want your output signal to go near zero, chose one that has output going very near to the negative rail. Nb: you can filter for rail-to-rail output (still check the datasheet for how close you can get to 0V)
- if you supply with 3.3V, then your output should also be able to go to the positive output rail or quite near. If you supply it with 5V, but only want 3.3V output signal, then you have far more margin (still check, for some op-amps, the max output voltage is several volts bellow supply voltage)

You should be able to find hundreds of MOSFETs that suit your needs.

2. C2 is useless: you are consuming no (or negligible) current at the V+ node of the OPAMP, so there is no need to stabilize the voltage (excepted if your 3.3V source is very noisy, and/or you want such precision that noise starts to matter. A small decoupling capacitor (100nF) between the supply pins of the OP-AMP (and as near as possible) is always a good idea.

The values of R4 and R5 are fine (if you are not aiming at very low noise, you can increase them both to 100k to reduce current consumption

Comment: thank you, very helpful. I'll get rid of C2 and ill add a 100nF cap across the supply terminals.